# How can I match valid sequence of operation using Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I just started to learn about Regular Expression with Java. I have this project from [hyperskill.com](http://hyperskill.com) called "Smart Calculator" it is like the Python interpreter where you can input a arithmetic operation and when you press enter there is an output.

I would like to match if the input is valid like `2 + 2 - 3` and won't match if the input is `2 + 2 -` .

I have these regular expression `(\s*[0-9]+\s*[\+\-\*\/]+\s*[0-9]+\s*){1,}`

But when I tried to test with some inputs...

```
[In]    1 + 1
[Out]   Matched

[In]    1 + 1 + 1    // Not matched
[Out]   Not Matched

[In]    1 + 12 + 1  //But this one matched
[Out]   Matched
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Sorry, I am just new to this forum, and I cant proceed to my project because I'm stuck with these problem, btw sorry for the bad english

Comment: https://www.regextester.com/97778 and try `[0-9]+ \+ [0-9]+ \+ [0-9]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex, `(\s*[0-9]+\s*([+-]+\s*[0-9]+\s*)*)`. Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/z1YQox/2) for an explanation of the regex.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "1 + 1", "1 + 1 + 1", "2 + 2 - ", "2 + 2 - 3", "1 + 12 + 1" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + s.matches("(\\s*[0-9]+\\s*([+-]+\\s*[0-9]+\\s*)*)"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 + 1 => true
1 + 1 + 1 => true
2 + 2 -  => false
2 + 2 - 3 => true
1 + 12 + 1 => true
```

Comment: Okay I get it, so i need to capture the sub group containing the operator and the right operand. Thanks it is now working.

Comment: There is no need to escape `-` and `+` in a `[-+]`  or  `[+-]` character class. `-` is always at the start/end of the class and is thus parsed as a literal `-` char. `+` is not special in a character class.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew for the valuable information. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Why does it not match if i have an input "1 + ", when the sub group is captured zero or more ?

Comment: The regex `([+-]+\s*[0-9]+\s*)*` says that `+` or `-` needs to be followed by zero or more space and **one** or more digits followed by zero or more space. And finally, the whole group can occur zero or more times. I hope, it clears your doubt. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: Sorry if this is a none sense question, if the input is matched like "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5"  why do i get only " + 5" if i get the group(2)?.......is the group(2) overwritten everytime it captures the sub-group?

Comment: `group(2)` is returning the value as expected i.e. a `+` or `-` sign followed by an integer number. You have to use either `group()` i.e. full match or `group(1)`. Check https://regex101.com/r/z1YQox/3 for a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

`[a-z]` is regexpese for: Any character between a and z. So, your `[+-*/]` is regexpese for: "Any character having a unicode codepoint value between the codepoint value of `+` and the codepoint value of `*` which is problematic. Try putting the `-` at the start or end, in which case it does mean literally the `-` character, or escape it. So, make that: `[-+*/]`.

Secondly, your regexp is for:

- A number
- an operator
- A number

which you then state as: This, at least once or more (note that `{1,}` is just a silly way of writing `+`!

thus, you've set up the regexp to look for example for:

- A number
- an operator
- A number
- A number
- an operator
- A number

That duplication of 'a number' in the middle is your problem. The reason `1+12+1` matches is because your regexp matches that as `1+1` followed by `2+1`. That's also the reason why `1+1+1` does not match.

The solution is to start with a number, and then repeat only the 'operator, then number' part.

Note that `\d` is short for digit, shorter than [0-9].

Finally, you've said that any number of operators is okay, which makes no sense. try it: `1++1` is valid according to your regex here.

Putting it all together:

```
\s*\d+(\s*[-+*/]\s*\d+)+
```

is all you need.